# write a function that could convert from hex to ascii format within pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write the function that could take data frame (df) and column(col) as input and convert from encoded HEX to ascii within the column .

i have tried `"7061756c".decode("hex")` but i am not sure i could i apply for entire records in the column col , below is the code i tried

```
def hex_to_ascii(df , col):
    for i in range(0,len(df['col'].values)):
        string = bytearray.fromhex(df['col'].values[i]).decode()
```

i am stuck here , could someone help on this

Comment: Can you show some sample of your data?

Comment: due to privacy i can not but for your information each record of one particular column having only hex format

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you only really need to use `df.apply()` with a modified version of your function if I'm understanding your dataframe correctly:

```
def hex_to_ascii(s):
    try:
        return bytearray.fromhex(s).decode()
    except ValueError:
        return None      # or s, or some other error handling

df['col'] = ['7061756c', '6a6f686e', '72696e676f', '67656f726765', '737475', '796f6b6f']
print(df['col'].apply(hex_to_ascii))

0      paul
1      john
2     ringo
3    george
4       stu
5      yoko
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Comment: Throwing below errors >> ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 1, could you please help us to understand

Comment: That means that your column has some non-hexadecimal values in it. You can add a `try... except` to your `hex_to_ascii` function to deal with those.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [16]: df = pd.DataFrame({"col":["a", "b", "xyz"]})

In [17]: df["encoded"] = df["col"].apply(lambda x: x.encode().hex())

In [18]: df["decoded"] = df["encoded"].str.decode("hex")

In [19]: df
Out[19]:
   col encoded decoded
0    a      61    b'a'
1    b      62    b'b'
2  xyz  78797a  b'xyz'

In [22]: df["decoded"] = df["encoded"].apply(lambda x: bytes.fromhex(x).decode())

In [23]: df
Out[23]:
   col encoded decoded
0    a      61       a
1    b      62       b
2  xyz  78797a     xyz

In [25]: df["decoded"] = df["encoded"].str.decode("hex").str.decode("utf-8")

In [26]: df
Out[26]:
   col encoded decoded
0    a      61       a
1    b      62       b
2  xyz  78797a     xyz
```

Comment: Nice - I like the good and thorough use of the `str.decode` builtin.